# Refresh Token stateless vs stateful?

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I already know what is different between stateless/stateful Access Token.

What is different between stateless/stateful **Refresh Token**? is the same as Access Token?

Why Google and Auth0 use stateful refresh token?

Why Keycloak use stateless refresh token?

example keycloak stateless refresh token

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI3ZTVmNzhhYy05ODVmLTRjMTgtYmMwYS1kMDJjZDFlOGRhNGQifQ.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.Hsaib16poW3SW0EYUB80jU0HyseZi_Ui9tj_2QJAZ-w
```

I read this topic [Oauth 2: why refresh tokens must be stateful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987471/oauth-2-why-refresh-tokens-must-be-stateful) but I still don't understand.

Comment: In general, any airtight JWT implementation can't really work without storing at least some state about the tokens which exist, did exist, were blacklisted, etc.  So, you won't find too many pure stateless implementations out there.  As for the link you cited, I don't completely agree with the accepted answer, and a refresh token needs to be monitored as much as any other token in the JWT pattern.

Comment: can I use refresh token as jwt format for reducing the load on the DB? If refresh token valid signature the server renew access token.

Comment: AFAIK both the refresh and access tokens use very similar formats, so the answer to your question is yes.